# Automatically assigning abbreviations to an index in ConTeXt

Tags: context, indexing

I'm using ConTeXt to provide layout for my thesis across many files comprising the project.

I would like to automatically generate an index based on keywords and abbreviations with minimal hinting by me. I suspect the

`\setupsynonyms[abbreviation][command=\index]`

command has the ability to add abbreviations to the index automatically, but I haven't found an invocation that actually works.

Is there a command for ConTeXt that provides either level of automatic index generation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slightly tricky. You need to use `synonymcommand` to set up the command that is used when the short form of the synonym is called. You also need to expand the argument of `synoyncommand`. Here is an example

```
\setupsynonyms[abbreviation][synonymcommand=\indexedentry]

\def\indexedentry#1{#1\expanded{\index{#1}}}

\abbreviation {AMS} {American Mathematics Association}

\starttext
\AMS\ is an abbreviation for \infull{AMS}

\subject {Index}
\placeindex[criterium=all]
\stoptext
```

Comment: I ran your code in ConTeXt and unfortunately the AMS reference did not show up in the index. (Tested both in my main document and by copy/pasting your code directly into a clean one.) (this is my first "oops" comment here, how do I make this comment more useful? I'm running the latest minimals as of yesterday.)

Comment: @Brian: I tested with a week old MkiV. I'll test again with the latest beta

Comment: To be fair, I've gotten an odd color error that suggests that I'm not doing things right. I'll reverify my setup tomorrow.

Comment: @Brian: Are you using MkII or MkIV? If you want help with debugging when something goes wrong, it is better to ask the question on the context mailing list.

Comment: I *think* I'm using MkIV but I've got a suspicion that MkII snuck in there.

Comment: @Brian: The second line of the log file specifies the format that you are using.

Comment: I was using `texexec` instead of `context` Your solution works. Sorry to have been a bother.